# JMeter - Execute multiple test plans from single console

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter. I have created several test plans. Is it possible to combine different test plans in a single '.jmx' file so that the user can see all the different test plans in one console? Not only that, the user can pick and choose more than one test plans and run them? The test plans may not be collaborating with each other. Theyare completely isolated test plans. The idea is, the user can view and execute them from one console?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, looking into [`Adding and Removing Elements`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-test-plan.html#add_remove) chapter of [Building a Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-test-plan.html) article:

> Adding elements to a test plan can be done by right-clicking on an element in the tree, and choosing a new element from the "add" list. **Alternatively, elements can be loaded from file and added by choosing the "merge"** or "open" option.

[image]

---

You can also store multiple .jmx scripts as [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and add them to the "main" script via [Include Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) and/or [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller)

Check out [How to Manage Large JMeter Scripts With JMeter Test Fragments](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments/) article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

instead of maintaining multiple test plans .. i would suggest make multiple thread groups in one test plan so whoever going to use specific group then can enable and run ..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can add multiple test plans in one JMX file, as above comment says you can create multiple Thread groups in one test plan.

1. You can even create a test plan with JDBC request to test Data base and another test plan with Http request to API tests.
2. Add different headers and Listeners in each thread group as needed.
3. If you want aggregate report of all thread groups, you can listener by right clicking on Test Plan.